# Magento number of sites limit

Tags: magento

I'd like to accomodate 500 websites into Magento.
By this, I am into a trouble of knowing the number of sites limitation for a single instance of Magento. Anyone knows?
(I know that even the limitation may be higher 500 sites on Magento is crazy, but I need to know the limit)

On the other hand, would it be better to have 500 different instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no limitation to how many sites you can have in one Magento instance. But 500 would be crazy, and I would not recommend it at all. If each website has 1,000 products, that is 500,000 products that you are managing from one instance. Everything from index management to catalog search would take forever. A better idea would be to split the sites up into clusters, and have 1 instance per 15 to 20 stores, or have 500 different instances as you said.